# Google analytics IOS - Several trackevents between two dispatch

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, dispatch

I have a little problem with the google analytics API on IOS.

When I try to track two events, or two page views, between two dispatches (called automatically with the dispatchedPeriod), the second event is never fired. 
When I set the debug flag to YES, it shows that the dispatcher is busy...

Moreover, if I try to restart the app, every new event will be added on the event stack but never called neither.

Everything is working fine if I call the dispatch methods of the shared GANTracker just after the tracking calls, but with this solution, the dispatchedPeriod just become useless...

Anyone has encountered the same issue ?

Thanks !

EDIT : it seems to work with 3G connection but not with WIFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved !

It was a network configuration problem.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the network configuration problem was, and what the fix is? That way anyone else reading this with the same problem can try the fix.